# asp.net embedded twitter disappearing after postback asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

my embedded twitter feed is disappearing after partial postback
I've tried adding the below

```
function pageLoad() {

         $.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");

   }
```

to the the aspx page but still nothing - also tried the same using scriptmanager on page load in code behind

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "setDOM", "$.getScript(//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js);", true);
```

But its still blank
. I believe its not working because the widget has disappeared after postback just need to know how to add it back

```
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPanelCameraBtns" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCamHall" EventName="Click" />
                         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCamOutside" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>

            <div class="myIframe">
                    <iframe id="Camera" src=<%=cameraUrl%> "mozallowfullscreen=true webkitallowfullscreen=true allowfullscreen=true" 
                    style="border:none" scrolling="no"></iframe>
          </div>                                              
                </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">

            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#19CF86" href="https://twitter.com/AylesburyMasjid" data-tweet-limit="4">Tweets by AylesburyMasjid</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>              
              </div>
              </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageLoad() {
  $.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
}
```

Worked fine for me actually. You might have some 3rd party controls or who knows what that might stop it from working. I'm not a fan of using the magic pageLoad method. Having said that, the reason why this line isn't working:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "setDOM", "$.getScript(//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js);", true);
```

Is because you aren't quoting the string properly. It should be

```
$.getScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js')
```

not

```
$.getScript(//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js)
```

If you turn on your F12 tools, you'd see a JavaScript error. With that change, everything seems to work fine.